# Define ImageResizer settings runtime

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

In my MVC web application, I have a `Tech.UI` layer which all the user interface related components are located in there.

I want to use [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/) to generate thumbnail in my web application. I saw the configuration which should be set in `web.config` file.

As the settings will not be changed without building the `Tech.UI` project, is there anyway to define all the configuration outside of web.config file? How should I define the settings on run-time or statically hard-coded?

Here is my sample web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <section name="resizer" type="ImageResizer.ResizerSection,ImageResizer" requirePermission="false" />
      </configSections>
      <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Version" value="2.0.0.0" />
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
        <add key="PreserveLoginUrl" value="true" />
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
      </appSettings>
      <system.web>
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
        <pages>
          <namespaces>
            <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
            <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
          </namespaces>
        </pages>
        <httpModules>
          <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </httpModules>
      </system.web>
      <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
        <modules>
          <add name="ImageResizingModule" type="ImageResizer.InterceptModule" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
          <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
          <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
          <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true" />
        </security>
      </system.webServer>
      <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
          <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
          </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
      </runtime>
      <resizer>
        <remotereader signingKey="blahblahblah" allowAllSignedRequests="false" allowRedirects="5">
          <allow domain="*" />
        </remotereader>
        <diskCache dir="~/img/t" autoClean="false" hashModifiedDate="true" enabled="true" subfolders="32" cacheAccessTimeout="15000" asyncWrites="false" asyncBufferSize="10485760" />
        <pipeline fakeExtensions=".ashx" />
        <plugins>
          <add name="MvcRoutingShim" />
          <add name="DiskCache" />
          <add name="RemoteReader" />
          <add name="SeamCarving" />
        </plugins>
      </resizer>
    </configuration>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several different ways to do this:

1. Externalize that part of Web.Config using [configSource](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/06/16/Keep-your-config-clean-with-external-config-files.aspx).
2. Use `Config.Current.setConfigXmlText(xml)` to replace the XML configuration.
3. Install all plugins via code `new Plugin(settings).Install(Config.Current)`, configuring the instances directly. Make sure there are no conflicting XML settings, as those may get loaded instead.
4. Implement `ICurrentConfigProvider` as a plugin to control which `Config` instance is used based on the current HTTP request (or lack of one). If you want to completely replace the primary instance, this is how. All calls to `Config.Current` get delegated to the first responding `ICurrentConfigProvider` plugin.
5. Don't use `Config.Current`. Create and manage your own instance(s) of `ImageResizer.Configuration.Config`. Note that some plugins can't have multiple instances per application (DiskCache) or process (Faces, RedEye, PdfRenderer).